# How to read unstructured ASCII data in numpy?

Tags: numpy, ascii

I need to read unstructured ASCII data into numpy arrays. As an example, a file could look like this:

```
August 2005  OMI/MLS Tropo O3 Column (Dobson Units) X 10
Longitudes:  288 bins centered on 179.375W to 179.375E (1.25 degree steps)
Latitudes:  120 bins centered on -59.5S to 59.5N (1.00 degree steps)
 328322313320278255239243234240225243250276274188185228257307324334334266313
 302258249235303178184163133153233228193216245221235281235224200210217230239
 191168179199198202222218245272269260258253218217210250231221213216240220230
 216279262220205244255248266272235220215247221247253256261267284338317329327
 275288270253286272233215227999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999239
 242999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
 999999999999999999999999999636424663381417483472317200246338302140324258325
 317230243347274290259261255330322375318317342306373366375352345250278335368
 375393564999999999999999999999999999438341418448231272245265308299313365342
 345314325296273307328359375259284351376369317330358317321366329340334339373
 407376272226292357341348382369355358374361347367379368403379381398398391323
 347378367379364312306309280258236214206  lat =  -59.5
 316310310293280262250206199190174179239247204207187196190270280309302278294
 308261231270273168191184156219199179222218215193232261268223237236261272214
 236220178158177207189221200198234246226229180204217215226241245235215222225
 209205234227275264281264261234208289284263250249258265225251284273276301269
 239243250255236228260229255329236284274231245262999999999999999999999999999
 999999999999999459638999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
 366999999999999999999582427465386389430321336350319362400413409449373362351
 271274248359373294236244235229267275324307397319313380360399346279304265237
 247239249134219323393348313334215295273333329373309298298304349363369356338
 319343300279282287322317319324342311372379331353318288305319319373341352331
 354353342325316319356388409388344360388383361374397365361341379362384403407
 350343334328301279293228252243246231241  lat =  -58.5
```

After skipping the first three lines, each following 12 lines contain one row of the total 2D array. It's concatenated `int`s of three digits each.

Is there a way of doing this (somewhat) nicely in numpy? `loadtxt` needs a `delimiter` keyword, but I don't have a delimiter here, so I'm lost.

Of course it's possible to do this all *by hand*, i.e. manually reading the file, counting lines, splitting strings, and converting them individually. But that's quite cumbersome. So I'm looking for something more elegant.

**EDIT:** the `lat = XXXXX` can be ignored. I can easily reconstruct the latitudes from the header information.

Comment: Should we be ignoring the `lat = -59.5`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but it doesn't read it *"by hand"*.

```
nrows = 2
ncols = 25

nlines = 12
lastline = 13

a = np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt',
                  skip_header=3,
                  delimiter=[4]+[3,]*(ncols-1),
                  comments='l',
                  dtype=int)
a = a.reshape(nrows,-1)[:,:ncols*(nlines-1)+lastline]
```

You can use `delimiter = [length of widths]` which for you is `[4, 3, 3, 3, ...]` because the first value of each row has a space, which makes its width `4`.

You can ignore the `lat = ...` with `comments = 'l'`

The biggest problem is that you have to reshape and then cut off (because the last file line is shorter, the array is not 'rectangular' so it fills with `-1`s.  This requires you to know something about the shape/size of your file.

Comment: You're welcome!  With more information about the file, you might be able to make it more robust.  Like, replace `nrows = 2` with `(latmax-latmin)/latstep`, e.g..  That last line is a real pain :P